# How to get binary string from ArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

What is the way to obtain binary string from ArrayBuffer in JavaScript?

I don't want to encode the bytes, just get the binary representation as String.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't fully understand what conversion you are actually trying to accomplish, can you give some further explanation to clarify what you want?

Answer (score 20):

The following code will consistently convert an `ArrayBuffer` to a `String` and back again without losing or adding any additional bytes.

```js
function ArrayBufferToString(buffer) {
    return BinaryToString(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.apply(new Uint8Array(buffer))));
}

function StringToArrayBuffer(string) {
    return StringToUint8Array(string).buffer;
}

function BinaryToString(binary) {
    var error;

    try {
        return decodeURIComponent(escape(binary));
    } catch (_error) {
        error = _error;
        if (error instanceof URIError) {
            return binary;
        } else {
            throw error;
        }
    }
}

function StringToBinary(string) {
    var chars, code, i, isUCS2, len, _i;

    len = string.length;
    chars = [];
    isUCS2 = false;
    for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= len ? _i < len : _i > len; i = 0 <= len ? ++_i : --_i) {
        code = String.prototype.charCodeAt.call(string, i);
        if (code > 255) {
            isUCS2 = true;
            chars = null;
            break;
        } else {
            chars.push(code);
        }
    }
    if (isUCS2 === true) {
        return unescape(encodeURIComponent(string));
    } else {
        return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.apply(chars));
    }
}

function StringToUint8Array(string) {
    var binary, binLen, buffer, chars, i, _i;
    binary = StringToBinary(string);
    binLen = binary.length;
    buffer = new ArrayBuffer(binLen);
    chars  = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= binLen ? _i < binLen : _i > binLen; i = 0 <= binLen ? ++_i : --_i) {
        chars[i] = String.prototype.charCodeAt.call(binary, i);
    }
    return chars;
}
```

I tested it by round-tripping the following values in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/potatosalad/jrdLV/

```
(String) "abc" -> (ArrayBuffer) -> (String) "abc"
(String) "aΩc" -> (ArrayBuffer) -> (String) "aΩc"
(Uint8Array) [0,1,255] -> (ArrayBuffer) -> (String) -> (Uint8Array) [0,1,255]
(Uint16Array) [0,1,256,65535] -> (ArrayBuffer) -> (String) -> (Uint16Array) [0,1,256,65535]
(Uint32Array) [0,1,256,65536,4294967295] -> (ArrayBuffer) -> (String) -> (Uint32Array) [0,1,256,65536,4294967295]
```

Comment: Thanks. What encoding it return from fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer and fileReader.readAsBinaryString ?

Comment: @aung `readAsBinaryString` is just a string of 0s and 1s based on conversion of the individual bytes to those.  There's no "encoding".  `readAsArrayBuffer` uses whatever mask you tell it (i.e. Uint8, Uint16, Uint32, etc.).

Comment: ArrayBufferToString() doesn't seem to convert an ArrayBuffer / Uint8Array correctly to a binary string. Testing with a PNG file and some bytes are added, some are changed. Most are correct, however. Do I something wrong? I read the PNG file with FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer() and then sent it to ArrayBufferToString().

Answer (score 14):

This has been made much simpler by additions to JavaScript in recent years – here's a one-line method to convert a Uint8Array into a binary-encoded string:

```js
const toBinString = (bytes) =>
  bytes.reduce((str, byte) => str + byte.toString(2).padStart(8, '0'), '');
```

Example:

```js
console.log(toBinString(Uint8Array.from([42, 100, 255, 0])))
// => '00101010011001001111111100000000'
```

If you're starting with an ArrayBuffer, create a Uint8Array "view" of the buffer to pass into this method:

```js
const view = new Uint8Array(myArrayBuffer);
console.log(toBinString(view));
```

Source: the [Libauth](https://libauth.org/) library ([binToBinString method](https://github.com/bitauth/libauth/blob/bdc1d67a3181cf6fcfe796a7b4ae36ee3f98af0a/src/lib/format/bin-string.ts#L25-L36))

Answer (score 3):

This will give you a binary string from a typed array

```
var bitsPerByte = 8;
var array = new Uint8Array([0, 50, 100, 170, 200, 255]);
var string = "";

function repeat(str, num) {
    if (str.length === 0 || num <= 1) {
        if (num === 1) {
            return str;
        }

        return '';
    }

    var result = '',
        pattern = str;

    while (num > 0) {
        if (num & 1) {
            result += pattern;
        }

        num >>= 1;
        pattern += pattern;
    }

    return result;
}

function lpad(obj, str, num) {
    return repeat(str, num - obj.length) + obj;
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(array, function (element) {
    string += lpad(element.toString(2), "0", bitsPerByte);
});

console.log(string);
```

Output is

```
000000000011001001100100101010101100100011111111
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/vUytT/)

Or perhaps you are asking about this?

```
function ab2str(buf) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}
```

Note: that using `apply` in this manner means that you can hit the argument limitation (some 16000 elements or so), and then you will have to loop through the array elements instead.

On [html5rocks](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String)

Comment: some explanation of what code is doing seems to be granted here

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a very old question, but I wanted to add one more possible case/solution since I landed on this from a search:

I wanted an async/await version of `FileReader.readAsBinaryString()` because I am a capricious person and the callback interface annoyed me:

```js
// Suppose `file` exists

let fr = new FileReader()
let string1

fr.onload = ({ target: { result }}) => string1 = result
fr.readAsBinaryString(file)

console.log(string1)
```

Additionally, MDN says that [`FileReader.readAsBinaryString()` only exists for backward compatibility, and `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()` is recommended instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString).

There are new methods available on `Blob`/`File` that give you [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text), [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer)s, and [stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/stream)s, but no binary strings. Heeding MDN's advice, I figured we could go from `ArrayBuffer` to binary string using the new methods, and indeed we can:

```js
// Again, suppose `file` exists

let ab, bufferToString, string2

bufferToString = (buffer) => {
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer)
    return bytes.reduce((string, byte) => (string + String.fromCharCode(byte)), "")
}

ab = await file.arrayBuffer()
string2 = bufferToString(ab)

console.log(string2)
```

Assuming this is done in the same browser console:

```
string1 === string2 // true
```

Whether this is intelligence or stupidity is left to the reader.

Comment: Note that `readAsBinaryString` is now deprecated.

Comment: @EduardoProcópioGomez I did note that. It's already in the answer and is literally the entire reason I came to my solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
function string2Bin(s) {
  var b = new Array();
  var last = s.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < last; i++) {
    var d = s.charCodeAt(i);
    if (d < 128)
      b[i] = dec2Bin(d);
    else {
      var c = s.charAt(i);
      alert(c + ' is NOT an ASCII character');
      b[i] = -1;
    }
  }
  return b;
}

function dec2Bin(d) {
  var b = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    b = (d%2) + b;
    d = Math.floor(d/2);
  }
  return b;
}
```