# Send file via Post using new SDK Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm searching to send a zip file to a server using the "Request" class from the new Firefox SDK for addons. This is my code:

```
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
var file = new FileUtils.File(pathToZipFile);
Request({
   url: serverURL,
   content: file,
   onComplete: function (response) {
       for (var headerName in response.headers) {
          console.log(headerName + " : " + response.headers[headerName]);
       }
       console.log("Response " + response.text );
    }
}).post();
```

But the error is:

> [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520009 (NS_ERROR_FILE_INVALID_PATH) [nsILocalFile.target]"  nsresult: "0x80520009 (NS_ERROR_FILE_INVALID_PATH)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/querystring.js :: stringify/< :: line 70"  data: no]

I have tried to do some checks and:

1. The server is on and receives normal GET and POST without files
2. The zip file is present and the path is right

Do you see any errors?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it with the Request module is to base a base64 encoded string to the `content` key. If you don't use this, then you can send data such as a `Blob` or `DOMFile` (`new File()`) instance.

But as we see in the SDK code, the request module sends the `data` variable on request (if its not a HEAD or GET request).

https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/request.js#L110

The `data` var is made by running `stringify` on anything passed to the `content` key:
https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/request.js#L76

Stringify makes it a string:
https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/f5fab7b242121dccfa4e55ac80489899bb9f2a41/lib/sdk/querystring.js#L30

So you have to send base64 encoded string. Or a binary string. Which sucks.

You can use the `sdk/io` module to read the file as an `ArrayBuffer` and then turn that `ArrayBuffer` into a base64 string or binary string.

This shows how to get a binary string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16365505/1828637