# Binary string to ArrayBuffer/TypedArray in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a binary string and I need to be able to convert it to an ArrayBuffer/TypedArray containing the 0-255 values of each octet. For example:

```js
const string = "01110100011001010111100001110100";

// should log an ArrayBuffer containing 116, 101, 120, and 116
console.log(stringToArrayBuffer(string));
```

My question is basically the reverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363419/how-to-get-binary-string-from-arraybuffer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple loop with [`parseInt(val, 2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) should do it:

```js
function stringToArrayBuffer(str) {
  const arr = new Uint8Array(str.length / 8);
  for(let i = 0; i<str.length; i+=8) {
    arr[i/8] = parseInt(str.slice(i, i+8), 2);
  }
  return arr;
}
const string = "01110100011001010111100001110100";

// should log an ArrayBuffer containing 16, 101, 120, and 116
console.log(stringToArrayBuffer(string));
```